# What is the difference between appendChild, insertAdjacentHTML, and innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I want to know what the difference is between `appendChild`, `insertAdjacentHTML`, and `innerHTML`.

I think their functionality are similar but I want to understand clearly in term of usage and not the execution speed.

1. For example, I can use `innerHTML` to insert a new tag or text into another tag in HTML but it replaces the current content in that tag instead of appends.
2. If I would like to do it that way (not replace) I need to use `insertAdjacentHTML` and I can manage where I want to insert a new element (`beforebegin`, `afterbegin`, `beforeend`, `afterend`)
3. And the last if I want to create (not insertion in current tag) a new tag and insert it  into HTML I need to use `appendChild`.

---

Am I understanding it correctly? Or are there any difference between those three?

Answer (score 25):

- [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)

  **From MDN:**

  > innerHTML sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.

  when writing to *`innerHTML`*, it will overwrite the content of the source element. That means the HTML has to be loaded and re-parsed. This is not very efficient especially when using inside loops.
- [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

  **From MDN:**

  > Adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the node already exists it is removed from current parent node, then added to new parent node.

  This method is supported by all browsers and is a much cleaner way of inserting nodes, text, data, etc. into the DOM.
- [`element.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML)

  **From MDN:**

  > parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position. *[ ... ]*

  This method is also supported by all browsers.

....

Answer (score 11):

The `appendChild` methods adds an element to the DOM.

The `innerHTML` property and `insertAdjacentHTML` method takes a string instead of an element, so they have to parse the string and create elements from it, before they can be put into the DOM.

The `innerHTML` property can be used both for getting and setting the HTML code for the content of an element.

Comment: This is the key. appendChild works with elements. 

innerHTML and insertAdjacentHTML take text to create elements.

Answer (score 3):

@Guffa did explain the main difference ie innerHTML and insertAdjacentHTML need to parse the string before adding to DOM.

In addition see this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/insertadjacenthtml-perf/3) that will tell you that generally appendChild is faster for the job it provides.

Answer (score 1):

One that I know `innerHTML` can grab 'inner html', `appendChild` and `insertAdjacentHTML` can't;

example:

```
<div id="example"><p>this is paragraph</p><div>
```

js:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
```

end then now

```
foo = '<p>this is paragraph</p>';
```

Comment: what does you mean by 'grab' sir what is it grab?

Answer (score 0):

**DOCS:**

[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

[insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML)

[innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)

[innerHTML vs appendChild() performance](http://glowfilter.com/blog/javascript-performance-testing-innerhtml-vs-appendchild/)

[insertAdjacentHTML vs innerHTML vs appendChild performance](http://jsperf.com/insertadjacenthtml-vs-innerhtml-vs-appendchild)

Answer (score 0):

the main difference is location (positioning) :
(elVar mean element saved to variable)

** elVar.innerHTML: used to sets/get text and tags (like ) inside an element (if u use "=" it replace the content and "+=" will add to the end.

** divElvar.appendChild(imgElVar): to add pure element  to the end of another element (or start with prepend) .

** insertedElVar.insertAdjacentElement(beforebegin,targetElvar): it insert element into spicific location before elVar (after it with "afterend").

-innerText: can replace/get/insertOnEnd text.but can read tags and text inside element with display:hidden  , cant insert on start .
-innercontent : show all text inc hidden , cant read html tags and it put empty spaces instead of them , cant insert on start
-innerHTML: read all set all , cant insert on start

-prepend : insert text at start of elvar (but cant use to get/replace text or html)
prepend was needed for start, after it made its easy to make append , not for a need , its just bcz lol