# javascript returning object htmlelement

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a calculator application. I created the following function to push the the current function to a div to display itself.

```
function addtoScreen(vTag){

      var screen = document.getElementById("screen");

      if(currentFunction.length == 1){

        var newCalc = document.createElement("p");    
        newCalc.setAttribute("class", "calc");

        var opInt = "<span>"+vTag+"</span>";

        newCalc.innerHTML = opInt;
        screen.innerHTML = newCalc;

      }else{
        var opInt = "<span>"+vTag+"</span>";
        newCalc = document.getElementById("screen").lastElementChild;
        newCalc.innerHTML = opInt;  

      }
    }
```

The if portion keeps returning [object HTMLParagraphElement] what am I doing wrong? I have tried to use .value but that just returns a null because the object is a entire element that does not have a value attribute.

Edit: I didn't mention that vTag is just a string being passed through from a function that pushs to a array.

Comment: please add your html, optionally as snippet.

Comment: `vTag` is a DOM element?  You should be able to use `vTag.outerHTML` to get its content

Comment: It looks like you are setting your `currentFunction.length = 1` rather than comparing the length to 1 `currentFunction.length == 1`.

Comment: I've made the adjustment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this (I commented out your old code):

```
function addtoScreen(vTag){

  var screen = document.getElementById("screen");

  if(currentFunction.length == 1){

    var newCalc = document.createElement("p");    
    //newCalc.setAttribute("class", "calc");
    newCalc.className = "calc";

    //var opInt = "<span>"+vTag+"</span>";
    var opInt = document.createElement("span");
    opInt.innerHTML = vTag;

    //newCalc.innerHTML = opInt;
    newCalc.appendChild(opInt);

    //screen.innerHTML = newCalc;
    screen.appendChild(newCalc);

  }else{
    //var opInt = "<span>"+vTag+"</span>";
    var opInt = document.createElement("span");
    opInt.innerHTML = vTag;

    newCalc = screen.lastChild;

    //newCalc.innerHTML = opInt;
      if(newCalc)
      {
    newCalc.appendChild(opInt);
      }
      else
      {
       screen.appendChild(opInt);   
      }

  }
```

}

Comment: That works, thanks. Why did appendChild work and innerHTML work? Is innerHTML only for assigning strings and appendChild for actual modifying the DOM?

Comment: Something like that...  Here is a link with a little more info:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126960/what-is-the-difference-between-appendchild-insertadjacenthtml-and-innerhtml)