# Best way to move loaded element

Tags: javascript

I wanna move the element which is already **loaded** to a different position.

I have referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127049/19743544

> The `appendChild` methods adds an element to the DOM.

> `insertAdjacentHTML` method takes a string instead of an element, so
> they have to parse the string and create elements from it

I can see that both `appendChild`and `insertAdjacentHTML` are actually meant to **create** an element instead of **moving** the loaded element to somewehre.

In the example below, how do I move the div `.apple` into the section `main` before the div `orange` ?

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main'),
  apple = document.querySelector('.apple'),
  orange = document.querySelector('.orange');
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class="orange"></div>
</section>

<div class="apple"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```
const main = document.querySelector('.main'),
const apple = document.querySelector('.apple'),
const orange = document.querySelector('.orange');

main.insertBefore(apple, orange);
```

Note that both insertBefore and appendChild (in case you want to add it in last position) will move the element if it already exists in the DOM

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position.